Implementing Inverter op-amp, calculating impedances in multisim
Consider the following circuit , i have couple of confusions before asking the question, so suppose the source Vin has a frequency of 1kHz and amplitude of 50mV, and also we set the potentiometer to 0% so its a short-circuit, how does varying the amplitude of the source Vin to a certain value produce a non-distorted output signal?
So my question about the impedance is how can i adjust the potentiometer to get the input signal to be inferior to the half of output signal?


Your circuit can be represented like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R3 is the variable resistance VR3 in your own diagram. The bottom schematic here is a simplified version of the original, where I've replaced the series combination of R3 and R18 with a single resistance equal to their sum:
$$ R_4 = R_3 + R_{18} $$
You are no doubt aware of the behaviour of this lower circuit, being a simple inverting amplifier. Gain \$G\$ is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= -\frac{R_{22}}{R_4} \times V_{IN} \\ \\
G &= \frac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} \\ \\
&= -\frac{R_{22}}{R_4}
\end{aligned}
$$
Replace R4 with what we know it to be from the upper circuit:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{OUT} &= -\frac{R_{22}}{R_4} \times V_{IN} \\ \\
&= -\frac{R_{22}}{R_3 + R_{18}} \times V_{IN}
\end{aligned}
$$
This equation contains everything you need to know in order to be able to calculate the response \$V_{OUT}\$ to any value of \$V_{IN}\$, given any value of R3, including zero, when the variable resistor is a "short-circuit", and including 100kΩ, and everything in between.
The question alludes to "distortion", which would only occur if you apply \$V_{IN}\$ such that it causes \$V_{OUT}\$ to fall outside the range −12V and +12V, and which is not possible given the op-amp's ±12V supplies. I assume by "distortion" you mean "clipping".
This means you will have to consider these maximum and minimum possible \$V_{OUT}\$ of ±12V, when evaluating the maximum permissible range of \$V_{IN}\$.
When you say "output signal is half of the input signal", (assuming you are referring to signal amplitudes) this is equivalent to gain being (negative) one-half, or \$G=-0.5\$. Again, the equations above permit you to derive a value for R3 which would yield that condition.

@ Simon Fitch - I suppose, it was not your intention to realize positive feedback?

@LvW you suppose right! Good call, thanks

Yes thank you so much sir Simon, ah about the distortion i dont even understand what they actually mean by that i thought someone here could have come across such behavior when dealing with op-amp and could tell me what to do. But its okey i skipped that question, again infinite thanks!
